# How can I insert a bounding box or polygon in a PostGIS geometry field?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon-creation, extents

I have a field in my table called 'geometry' that was created thus:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."sites" (
    "id" int8 DEFAULT nextval('sites_id_seq' :: regclass) NOT NULL,
    #... A few MORE fields 
    "geometry" "public"."geometry",
    CONSTRAINT "sites_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (OIDS = FALSE);
CREATE INDEX "index_sites_on_geometry" ON "public"."sites" USING gist (geometry);
```

I can create a point with the command:

```
UPDATE sites
SET geometry = ST_SetSRID (
    ST_MakePoint (44.28, - 96.68, 495),
    4326
),
WHERE
    ID = 12;
```

I would like to create a bounding box, but being new to the syntax have not been able to get the correct syntax.

My best attempt:

```
UPDATE sites
SET geometry = ST_SetSRID (
    ST_3DMakeBox (
        ST_MakePoint (44.2, - 96.6, 400),
        ST_MakePoint (44.3, - 97.0, 400)
    ),
    4326
)
WHERE
    ID = 1123;
```

Gives the error:

> Column has Z dimension but geometry does not

I get this error even after trying

1. wrapping the `ST_SetSRID(...)` in a select statement as some online examples show (though the select statement returns a 2D result)
2. using `ST_Envelope(ST_Makeline` as suggested by @mattmakesmaps

My apologies that I am new to this. I *have* been looking through the documentation and googling `postgis insert bouding box` etc, but at my level, this isn't clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [St_GeomFromText](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_GeomFromText.html) to add geometries in WKT format

```
UPDATE sites
SET  geometry = st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 3 3, 0 0))') 
WHERE ID = 1123
```

Comment: when I wrap your example in `select  st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((0 0, 1 1, 2 2, 3 3))')` I get " ERROR:  geometry contains non-closed rings"

Comment: Ooops sorry. Coordinates should end with the first point. I will edit

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the `ST_Envelope()` [function](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html).

Specifically, see the 2nd example using a LINESTRING geometry. Given a LINESTRING composed of two vertices that represent your points, you should be able to get back a Polygon geometry which might be more useful to you.

Comment: I still get the error "Column has Z dimension but geometry does not" with `update sites set geometry = ( select ST_SetSRID(ST_Envelope(ST_Makeline(ST_MakePoint(42.794448, -76.116081,  415),ST_MakePoint(42.79231, -76.116679,  415))),4326)) where id = 1123`

Comment: Is the column you're trying to load these data into a 3d column? If so you can use the `ST_Force_3D` function, as seen in [this previous question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109410/postgis-column-has-z-dimension-but-geometry-does-not)

Comment: Based on your above example, the following SQL Statement outputs a Polygon Z geometry: `SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Force_3D(ST_SetSRID(ST_Envelope(ST_Makeline(ST_MakePoint(42.794448, -76.116081,  415),ST_MakePoint(42.79231, -76.116679,  415))),4326))) AS geometry`

Comment: The output is as follows:
                                                        `geometry                                                            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 POLYGON Z ((42.79231 -76.116679 0,42.79231 -76.116081 0,42.794448 -76.116081 0,42.794448 -76.116679 0,42.79231 -76.116679 0))
(1 row)
`

Comment: That works, but it broke my web application (likely because of how it queries lat & lon) as explained in [the bug report](https://github.com/PecanProject/bety/issues/129)). But I am still confused why the "Force3D" is required to output a Z geometry ... isn't that handled by the three arguments in `ST_MakePoint`?

Comment: `ST_Envelope` drops the Z dimension, making any geometry a 2D polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may need to think through the data type for `sites`. What is it for? It seems that  `geometry` is defined as `geometry(PolygonZ,4326)`, which I think is a bit silly. A polygon could be expressed as a 3D object if all the linear rings are coplanar (like a triangle or a lake). However, if it were, for example, the border of Nepal, why keep elevations with these coordinates? I'd argue it's nonsense, since you can't visualize this kind of `PolygonZ`.

If you want to keep the Z dimension, use `ST_Force3D` (or `ST_Force_3D` for older versions), which will assign a default Z of 0. Otherwise, you may want to change the geometry type to `geometry(Polygon,4326)`. Lastly, you could always use a `box3d` type, if you want to only store 3D boxes.

Lastly, your axis order is reversed. It is *always* (long, lat) for PostGIS.

Comment: We will want to keep elevation information, primarily because it informs the physical properties of the site (i.e., meteorology, hydrology).

Comment: That's not what I said. I was specifically singling out the meaning of a `PolygonZ` geometry. On the other hand, I think `PointZ` and `LineStringZ` are fantastic geometry types for features with elevation.