# Error using PostGIS query in MultipolygonZ type data

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, multi-polygon

I am using this query in MultipolygonZ type data in my PostgreSQL database, but I got error for so many times the data is not rendered properly in PostgreSQL with PostGIS extension.

PostGIS query:-

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('mapschema_178_17','layertable_2347_17','the_geom',4326)
```

WHERE database Schema is mapschema_178_17 and the table name is layertable_2347_17

Error:

```
ERROR:  Geometry has Z dimension but column does not
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "ALTER TABLE mapschema_178_17.layertable_2347_17 ALTER COLUMN the_geom TYPE  geometry(Geometry, 4326) USING public.ST_SetSRID(the_geom,4326);"
PL/pgSQL function updategeometrysrid(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,integer) line 80 at EXECUTE
SQL statement "SELECT public.UpdateGeometrySRID('',$1,$2,$3,$4)"
PL/pgSQL function updategeometrysrid(character varying,character varying,character varying,integer) line 5 at SQL statement
SQL state: 22023
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I think that same question has been asked and answered before: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109410/postgis-column-has-z-dimension-but-geometry-does-not.