# How do I UpdateGeometrySRID on table with mixed geometry sub types and mixed 2d/3d?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry, srid

I have a table where where SRID of my geometry is set to 0

I am trying to update the SRID using

```
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('location','geom',4326)
```

The equivalent DDL statement would be

```
ALTER TABLE public.location ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Geometry, 4326) USING public.ST_SetSRID(geom,4326)
```

However, I get an error

"[22023] ERROR: Geometry has Z dimension but column does not"

I understand that this is likely because my geometry column has mixed z (3d) and non-z (2d) information. I have seen some [solutions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109410/postgis-column-has-z-dimension-but-geometry-does-not) that force 3d or 2d using something like:

```
ALTER TABLE location ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MultiLineStringZ) USING ST_Force_3D(geom);
```

However, this solution won't work for me because I need to maintain the 2d/3d values and I have mixed sub types (MultiLineStringZ, Point, Polygon) and fully dynamic geometry column, so I can't specify the geometry subtype modifier (e.g `ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Geometry, 4326)` vs `ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(MultiLineStringZ)`).

Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053260/error-while-inserting-postgis-multipolygon-datatype-using-spring-jdbc) mentioned this type of issue but I can't figure out a solution.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to specify an `srid` using the generic `GEOMETRY` type (not the `geometry` typemod, which restricts to 2D). You can add a constraint though, like in [AddGeometryColumn](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/3e38e0b83b98925122bb22dff958a7a603ee4a42/postgis/postgis.sql.in#L2412)

Comment: @JGH Okay so if I understand correctly, there isn't a way to update/specify a srid for the generic geometry column type (which I am working with) so the work around would be to use AddGeometryColumn() and use the srid  (and generic geometry) constraints, then move my existing data into the new column?  Sorry if I am not understanding correctly/making sense. I am new to PostGIS and working on a database/schema that I didn't set up.

Comment: no no, sorry, it was meant to illustrate what to do, i.e. to add a constraint to the column preventing geometry with a different SRID from being inserted, something like `ALTER TABLE location ADD CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_geom CHECK (st_srid(geom) = 4326);` Of course you would still have to update the srid of each row first `UPDATE location SET geom = st_setsrid(geom,4326);`