# Create half ellipsoid on Postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

I have a positions of half ellipsoid, these numbers represent coordinates of ellipsoid:
[image]

But when I try to save this coordinates, it throws an error like:

> Geometry has Z dimension but column does not

I'm a newbie at Postgis, does anybody know how can I fix it?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/109410/29431

Comment: Can you share your query, or a simplified version of it which raises the same error?

Answer (score 1):

This error message basically tells you that the geometry column in the database is not a 3D geometry (it doesn't have the Z value), hence you have to create, e.g. a `POINTZ` instead of a `POINT`. Same goes for `LINESTRING` and `POLYGON` and their "MULTI" versions.

> ##### 28.1. 3-D Geometries
>
> So far, we have been working with 2-D geometries, with only X and Y
> coordinates. But PostGIS supports additional dimensions on all
> geometry types, a “Z” dimension to add height information and a “M”
> dimension for additional dimensional information (commonly time, or
> road-mile, or upstream-distance information) for each coordinate.
>
> For 3-D and 4-D geometries, the extra dimensions are added as extra
> coordinates for each vertex in the geometry, and the geometry type is
> enhanced to indicate how to interpret the extra dimensions. Adding the
> extra dimensions results in three extra possible geometry types for
> each geometry primitive:
>
> - Point (a 2-D type) is joined by PointZ, PointM and PointZM types.
> - Linestring (a 2-D type) is joined by LinestringZ, LinestringM and LinestringZM types.
> - Polygon (a 2-D type) is joined by PolygonZ, PolygonM and PolygonZM types.
>
>   And so on.

Source: the [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) documentation for all the details: https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/3d.html

For example, create a table for storing 3D point geometries as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    geom geometry(POINTZ, 3857) -- for storing 3D point geometries
  );
```

Instead of:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    geom geometry(POINT, 3857) -- for storing 2D point geometries
  );
```

Notice the removal of the trailing `Z`.

See also the PostGIS documentation chapter [4.6.1. Creating a Spatial Table](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#Create_Spatial_Table).

Comment: Thank you for your response and thanks for not judging me for being a newbie. I want to share my query and here it is:

INSERT INTO public.geometries(shape) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POLYGONZ ((30.165195709898388 36.4578143393434 21157.624029629347, 30.165195709898388 36.4578143393434 21157.624029629347, 30.165195709898388 36.4578143393434 21157.624029629347, ...)))', 4326));